Georgian full text search solutions
I am developing a web application that should support the Georgian language. And I cannot implement the full text search.
I have various products in my app that have multiple text properties, such as title, description, etc. Initially, I tried to go with PostgreSQL and their tsvector feature. But PostgreSQL does not support Georgian by default, instead, I need to find and import Georgian dictionary and perform some magic like creating language configuration. It works but poorly (because of the quality of the dictionary). My app is not that big, so I thought I could also try SQLite but after going through the docs, I found out SQLite does not support FTS by default and it needs an extension. I feat the extension won't support Georgian either.
All I need is just a database or a tool of some sort that will certainly work with Georgian words out of the box and will perform a search. Maybe some AWS or Google Cloud solution, or possibly Elasticsearch (I've heard of it but they don't support Georgian by default I guess)?
I need a full text search solution for the Georgian language.

Any help?
